# OpenLayers import CspLine with KML

Tags: openlayers, ol-ext

I'm using the following code to draw [ol-ext cspline](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/geom/map.geom.cspline.html) in my OpenLayers project.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Draw Features</title>
    <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep@1.0.6/dist/elm-pep.js"></script>
    <!-- The lines below are only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,TextDecoder"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol-ext.css" />
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <a href="#" id="kmlBtn" download="file.kml">Download KML</a>
    <label>Import KML</label>
    <input type="file" id="importKML" />
    <script src="ol.js"></script>
    <script src="ol-ext.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the js file :-

```
 //main.js
    const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    
    const source = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
    
    const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source
    });
    
    const map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [raster, vector],
      target: "map",
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
      })
    });
    
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: "LineString"
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    
    draw.on("drawstart", function (event) {
      event.feature.set("line_color", "#ff0000");
      event.feature.set("line_width", 2);
      var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: event.feature.get("line_color"),
          width: event.feature.get("line_width")
        })
      });
      event.feature.setStyle(lineStyle);
    });
    draw.on("drawend", function (event) {
      event.feature.setStyle(stylefun(event.feature));
      event.feature.set("cspline", true);
    });
    
    var downloadBtn = document.getElementById("kmlBtn");
    var importBtn = document.getElementById("importKML");
    
    downloadBtn.onclick = function () {
      var sourceProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
      var formatKML = new ol.format.KML();
      var featuresArr = [];
      source.forEachFeature(function (feature) {
        var f = feature.clone();
        f.setGeometry(f.getGeometry().transform(sourceProjection, "EPSG:4326"));
        featuresArr.push(f);
      });
    
      var kml_str = formatKML.writeFeatures(featuresArr);
      var doc = $.parseXML(kml_str);
      var output = $(doc).find("kml").prop("outerHTML");
      var base64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(output)));
    
      $("#kmlBtn").attr(
        "href",
        "data:application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;base64," + base64
      );
    };
    importBtn.onchange = function (event) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var kml = e.target.result;
        importKML(kml);
      };
      reader.readAsText(importBtn.files[0]);
    };
    
    function importKML(kmlString) {
      var formatKML = new ol.format.KML();
      var kmlFeatures = formatKML.readFeatures(kmlString);
      var sourceProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
      kmlFeatures.forEach(function (feature, i) {
        var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: feature.get("line_color"),
            width: feature.get("line_width")
          }),
          geometry: feature.getGeometry()
        });
        //feature.setStyle(stylefun(feature))
        //feature.setGeometry(feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', sourceProjection) )
        feature.setGeometry(
          lineStyle.getGeometry().transform("EPSG:4326", sourceProjection)
        );
        vector.getSource().addFeature(feature);
      });
      vector.setMap();
    }
    
    function stylefun(feature) {
      var geom = feature.getGeometry();
      var csp = geom.cspline({ tension: 0.8, pointsPerSeg: 10 });
      var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: feature.get("line_color"),
          width: feature.get("line_width")
        }),
        geometry: csp
      });
      var point1 = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "blue", width: 1 }),
          radius: 1
        }),
        geometry: new ol.geom.MultiPoint(csp.getCoordinates())
      });
      var point2 = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "red", width: 4 }),
          radius: 2
        }),
        geometry: new ol.geom.MultiPoint(geom.getCoordinates())
      });
      return [lineStyle, point1, point2];
    }
```

I am able to export these drawings as kml file. The issue is, when I import it back, it drawn as normal Line String.  I couldn't figure it out how to convert it back to cspline. You can see a working [sample here](https://1yqb9f.csb.app/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is styling the drawn line as cspline.  To save it you must convert it to cspline.

Either when drawn by changing

```
  event.feature.set("cspline", true);
```

to

```
  event.feature.setGeometry(event.feature.getGeometry().cspline({ tension: 0.8, pointsPerSeg: 10 }));
```

Or when exporting by changing

```
  f.setGeometry(f.getGeometry().transform(sourceProjection, "EPSG:4326"));
```

to

```
  f.setGeometry(f.getGeometry().cspline({ tension: 0.8, pointsPerSeg: 10 }).transform(sourceProjection, "EPSG:4326"));
```